# symfony 4 Call to a member function guessExtension() on string

Tags: upload, symfony4

I'm using symfony 4 and I'm trying to upload an image but I got stuck with this error 'Call to a member function guessExtension() on string' :( .
I've made sure that the mimeTypes are right but when I debug  I got this "This file is not a valid image."

Part of class Group:

```
 /**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",name="logo",length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, upload the logo as a PNG file.")
 * @Assert\Image(mimeTypes={" image/png "})
 */
private $logo="";
```

Function newGroup of GroupController

```
  public function newGroup(Request $request)
{
    $group = new Group();
    $action = $this->generateUrl('new_group');
    $form = $this->createForm(GroupType::class, 
    $group,array('method'=>'POST', 'action'=>$action));
    $form->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label'=>'Save'));

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if(  $form->isSubmitted()  )
    {
        /**
         * @var UploadedFile $file
         */
        $file = $group->getLogo();
        $fileName = $this->generateUniqueFileName().'.'.$file->guessExtension();
        $file->move(
         $this->getParameter('logos_directory'),$fileName);
        $group->setLogo($fileName);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($group);
        $em->flush();
    }
    return $this->render('admin/group/new.html.twig', array('form'=>$form->createView()));
}
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have used Form then replace

```
$file = $group->getLogo();
```

with something like

```
$file = $form->get('image_name');
```